# How to create a separate histograms for different years in panel data?

Tags: r

I have a data frame newspaper_yearly, which contains the circulation ($CIRC) for a set of newspapers per year. I want to see how the distribution of these numbers change over time. So I want to create multiple, separate histograms for these different years.

I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(newspaper_yearly,aes(x=CIRC))+geom_histogram()+facet_grid(~YEAR==2004)+theme_bw()
```

But this shows two histograms, one where YEAR==2004 is true, and one where YEAR=2004 is not true. I want to only see the histogram for when YEAR=2004 is true.

Edit:
here's a cleaned up sample of the basic data structure:

```
      YEAR   CIRC
45938 1972  16557
10396 1900   2320
56311 2000   1195
1002  1872   1200
53335 1992  17764
7376  1896   1760
30101 1940 100651
18633 1916  11956
3171  1884   1900
54022 1992   5530
38751 1956   8006
42125 1964  10208
636   1872   1500
48706 1980  18830
22497 1924     NA
28024 1936   7211
7684  1896  21752
56087 2000 107129
43935 1968   9288
34692 1948   5083
```

I understand I could just make a subset like this (which is effectively the result I want), but I want to circumvent making a subset for every single year.

```
datahist2000 <- newspaper_yearly[ which(newspaper_yearly$YEAR == "2000"), ]
hist(datahist2000$CIRC)
```

Comment: can you share a sample of the raw data

Comment: Difficult... I signed an NDA. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: some sample that highlights the structure of the data would do just fine

Comment: Added it in the edit.

Comment: @TheCurlyManLives, where did you get the data?

Comment: @edyvedy13 I used this dataset: http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/30261

Comment: @TheCurlyManLives Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(i in levels(d$YEAR)){
datahist <- d[which(d$YEAR == i), ]
hist(datahist$CIRC)}
```

I used your subset approach to solve the problem with a for loop. I don't quite know if that is what you are trying to accomplish. I presume that there are quite a few entries for 'CIRC' per year, right? Otherwise separate plots don't make much sense, at least not for the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a histogram for each year separately? In that case you can simply do

`ggplot(newspaper_yearly, aes(x = CIRC)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~YEAR) + theme_bw()`

In case, You want to group years in a more complicated way, I recommend adding a new variable group, such as the following

```
group_year<- function(year){
   if (year >= 1900 && year < 1980) return ("1900 - 1980")
   if (year >= 1980 && year < 2020) return ("1980 - 2020")
   return ("default")
}
newspaper_yearly$group = sapply(newspaper_yearly$YEAR, group_year)
ggplot(newspaper_yearly, aes(x = CIRC)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~group) + theme_bw()
```