# How can I separate categorical variables two make two different graphs in r?

Tags: r

So let's say I want to make two histograms that compare whether sleeping time is related with being a veteran or not. I have data on "veteran status" (which holds values of "yes" or "no") and I have quantitative data on sleeping time (in hours). I want to make a histogram that holds the sleeping time of veterans, and sleeping time of non-veterans. But I do not know how to separate the data into veterans and non-veterans. Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use `ggplot2` and `facet` on your veteran status variable. If you read the tutorials on ggplot and the related `facet*` functions you should be able to figure it out. If you have problems, come back and ask a specific question about that! Good luck!

Comment: Please show what your data looks like. Have you imported it into R? Is it in a data frame? If it is in a data frame named `dd` and has column `vet` and `sleep`, you could do this: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(dd, aes(x = sleep)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~vet)`, but there are many other ways as well. Posting a small example of your data and showing what you've tried so far will help us help you. For now, your question doesn't include enough detail to really be answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683200/how-to-create-a-separate-histograms-for-different-years-in-panel-data?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach, assuming your table looks like `dat` below:

```
library(ggplot2)

# generate some fake data that sounds like what OP's table is 
dat <- data.frame(vet = sample(c("yes","no"), size=1e3, replace=TRUE), 
                  sleep = round(runif(1e3, min=1, max=5)) + sample(1:4, 1))

# make a histogram of `$sleep` grouped by `$vet` status: 
ggplot(dat, aes(x=sleep, fill=vet)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="dodge", bins=5)
```

The output will look like this: [image: grouped histogram]

Or you can produce side-by-side histograms (one for `"yes"` veteran, one for `"no"`), like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=sleep)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="dodge", bins=5) + 
  facet_wrap(~vet)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 2 separate datasets, then you can use the `subset` function like this:

```
df_veterans <- subset(df, veteran_status == "yes")
df_non_veteran <- subset(df, veteran_status == "no")
```

Alternately, you could also try:

```
df_veterans <- df[veteran_status == "yes", ]
df_non_veteran <- df[!(veteran_status == "yes"), ]
```